# Python PyQt6 DLL load failed

Tags: python, pyqt6

Whenever i have

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QFileDialog
from PyQt6.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt6 import uic
```

I am getting error:

> from PyQt6 import QtCore ImportError: DLL load failed while importing
> QtCore:

Before that i added to my program

```
import subprocess
import sys

def install_requirements():
    try:
        with open('requirements.txt', 'r') as f:
            requirements = f.read().splitlines()
        subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', *requirements])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Library instalation failed: {e}")

install_requirements()
```

And then no Qt program runs.

Use and run Qt library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution:

Uninstall all modules related to PyQt6. But only using **PowerShell**.

```
pip3 uninstall -y PyQt6 pyqt6-plugins PyQt6-Qt6 PyQt6-sip pyqt6-tools qt6-applications qt6-tools
```

Reinstall PyQt6.

```
pip3 install PyQt6
```